# Authentication plugin imap not found. moodle server 3.4.2

Tags: linux, centos-7, moodle

OS I am using `CentOS 7.0`

I upgraded Moodle server from 2.7 to 3.0 everything was working fine.
Later I upgraded from 3.0 to 3.4.

After upgrading I am only able to login only  Moodle `admin` account, rest of the ldap users I am not able to login.

But if I check my ldap settings from admin account it's showing below message.

[image]

And If I try to change any ldap user settings It's showing below error message.

[image]

And I if I try to login using ldap account in /var/log/httpd/error.log I am getting below message.

`[Thu May 03 15:54:59.645648 2018] [:error] [pid 10601] [client 192.168.1.34:47792] [client 192.168.1.34]  http://********.com  Disabled Login:  **username**  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0, referer: http://******.com/login/index.php`

I think issue related to php version

Moodle 2.7 and 3.0 using PHP 5.4.4 so upgrade working.

But Moodle 3.4 using PHP 7.0.0 upgrade not working.

Need to change anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not mentioned in the release notes, but auth_imap has been removed from core into a separately installable plugun. See https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Upgrading:

> #### Possible issues that may affect you in Moodle 3.4
>
> - The following authentication plugins were removed from core and can be found at the following URLs. If you use them, you must provide them manually during the upgrade ([MDL-50925](http://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-50925)).
>
>   - FirstClass (auth_fc) - https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-auth_fc
>   - IMAP Mail server (auth_imap) - https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-auth_imap
>   - Network News Transfer Protocol (auth_nntp) - https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-auth_nntp
>   - Pluggable Authentication Modules (auth_pam) - https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-auth_pam
>   - POP3 Mail server (auth_pop3) - https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-auth_pop3.

*(Personally I'd suggest either a SAML2 single-signon system, or LDAP.)*